# Disable connection and consumer creation in spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have written a simple kafka configuration and consumer class as below:

Consumer:

```java
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    /**
     * This consumer listens for policy download acknowledgements.
     *
     * @param downloadAck message
     */
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.pd.consumer.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.pd.consumer.group}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void policyDownload(final String downloadAck) {
        //some processing here
    }
```

Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value("${kafka.connect.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        TMLogger.info(()->"[consumerFactory] Kafka servers {}", url);
        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, url);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, VerticalEnum.HEALTH.name());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

Now the catch is I need to disable this on dev environment.

I tried disabling bean creation for `KafkaConfiguration` class, but then that threw an exception in `KafkaConsumer` as it's unable to find the `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean.

Spring-kafka version : `"org.springframework.kafka" % "spring-kafka" % "2.2.7.RELEASE"`

Please suggest on how should I disable it.

Comment: you mean you don't want to consume messages from dev env?

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable `KafkaConfiguration` and `KafkaConsumer` beans in `dev` environment using `@Profile` annotation

```
@Service
@Profile("!dev")  //will load this bean other than dev profile
public class KafkaConsumer {
```

Same way for Config class

```
@EnableKafka
@Profile("!dev")
public class KafkaConfiguration {
```

Comment: You can also use the `autoStartup` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `autoStartup` property which is set to `false` in your test case.

```
`autostartup = "${consumer.enabled}"`
```